# Same looking PDF different printout

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I have two PDF file, one provided by someone and one by me. PDF contains only a background that looks like: [image]

In 1200% zoom.

Its extremely important to me to print both of them in as high quality as possible. The problem is that despite of both look the same in Adobe Reader, PDF provided by looks better. How it is possible and what can I do improve pdf printout?

Comment: You've only pictured one of the PDF files, so we can't see any difference, and you haven't provided either file. Without seeing the actual PDF file its impossible to say what the difference is.

Comment: There are only black strips on white background. In 6400% zoom they looks absolutely the same, pixel by pixel. I am sure this is not a problem.

Comment: Maybe .PDF contain information about how to print or something.

Comment: PDF doesn't contain device-dependent information, so that's unlikely. Its possible that the PDF can contain two different objexts, one for print and one for screen, but that's unusual. And unless you post the files, nobody will be able to tell you. Put them on a file sharing site and post the URL here and I'll look.

Comment: There are good PDFs https://www.neosmartpen.com/en/ncode-pdf/ and there is PDF generated by me https://files.fm/f/s7ugn36f. I know the strokes may be on different but it doesn't matter. All the strokes looks almost the same, have same strokes/inch ratio etc but printout is diferent (so different that the device that scan those strokes doesn't see strokes on my PDF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about either PDF file which has different content for printing. However.... The images which contain the 'background' are constructed rather differently.

The neopen file draws the background as an image in CMYK space.

The 'generated' file contains an image which is defined as being in a SoftMask group (transparency) which appears to be pointless since the transparency has no effect. In addition, the image itself is defined in a CalRGB space with a Perceptual rendering intent.

You have not said in what way you perceive the neopen original file to be superior to the 'generated' file when printed.

My guess would be that the colour management software in the printer (which is required to convert the CalRGB colours into the CMYK inks available to the printer) is producing subtly different colours and therefore slightly different rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your time